# Remove header row in Excel using pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have an Excel file with merge header that I read as dataframe using pandas. It looks like this after `pd.read_excel()`:

```
Unnamed: 0     Pair    Unnamed: 1      Type      ...  Unnamed: 23
cabinet_name   group     pair          caller_id ...  result
value1         value1    value1        value1    ...  value1
value2         value2    value2        value2    ...  value2
```

So it's like I have two header rows. One is the row with Unnamed and the other is my desired header row.

This is my desired output:

```
cabinet_name   group     pair          caller_id ...  result
value1         value1    value1        value1    ...  value1
value2         value2    value2        value2    ...  value2
```

I am trying to remove the **row** with `Unnamed`:

```
df.drop(df.index[[0]])
```

and also using `header=None` in `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx, header=None)'`

But all of what I found did not return my expected output. I searched on how to delete **rows** with `Unnamed` but all I found was deleting **columns**.

I also tried

```
df.drop(df.head(0))
```

but it returned me:

```
KeyError: '[\'Unnamed: 0\' \'Pair'\ ... \'Unnamed: 23\']'
```

Any best way to do it?

Comment: How working `pd.read_excel(file, header=[1])` ?

Comment: @jezrael the same KeyError as `df.drop(df.head(0))`

Comment: I think `df.drop(df.head(0))` id not necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need skip first row by parameters `skiprows=1` or `header=1` and then remove all only `NaN`s columns:

```
df = (pd.read_excel('UF_AGT702-M.xlsx', skiprows=2, sheetname='Report')
        .dropna(how='all', axis=1))
```

Comment: Both did not work. It's wierd. I used `print(df.head(0))` to view the headers. And I also used `to_excel()` to view the output as Excel file.

Comment: @RickyAguilar - Are data confidental?

Comment: Nope. Not confidentia. The **values** changes everyday.

Comment: @RickyAguilar - Super, is possible send me file to my email from my profile? Because it seems some data related problem.

Comment: Sent. I think you will get what i am trying to do once you see the file.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take for instance the excel file layout bellow.

[image]

To exclude the footer and header information from the datafile you could use the header/skiprows parameter for the former and skipfooter for the later. Here is a MWE for its use it:

```
import pandas as pd

energy = pd.read_excel('your_excel_file.xls', header=9, skipfooter=8)
```

> **header** : int, list of int, default 0
>   Row (0-indexed) to use for the column labels of the parsed DataFrame. If a list of integers is passed those row positions will be combined into a MultiIndex. Use None if there is no header.
>
> **skipfooter** : list-like
>   Rows at the end to skip (0-indexed).

Check out latest [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) documentation for further details.

Comment: Hi, this is helpful, but how would you remove columns if let's say your dataset starts from column B or C?