# Removing multiple headers in a single excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

Similar to [Remove header row in Excel using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700110/remove-header-row-in-excel-using-pandas)

I wish to remove headers from an excel sheet.

Using the same example but edited:

```
Company ABC

Account Name 1
Account No.1
Description    group     pair          amount    ...  result
value1         value1    value1        value1    ...  value1
value2         value2    value2        value2    ...  value2
totals                               sum values

Account Name 2
Account No.2
Description    group     pair          amount    ...  result
value3         value3    value3        value3    ...  value3
value4         value4    value4        value4    ...  value4
totals                               sum values

Sales
00234
Description    group     pair          amount    ...  result
value5         value5    value5        value5    ...  value5
value6         value6    value6        value6    ...  value6
totals                               sum values

Inventory
00012345
Description    group     pair          amount    ...  result
value7         value7    value7        value7    ...  value7
value8         value8    value8        value8    ...  value8
value9         value9    value9        value9    ...  value9
totals                               sum values
```

I wish to concatenate it to become like

```
cabinet_name   group     pair          amount    ...  result
value1         value1    value1        value1    ...  value1
value2         value2    value2        value2    ...  value2
value3         value3    value3        value3    ...  value3
value4         value4    value4        value4    ...  value4
value5         value5    value5        value5    ...  value5
value6         value6    value6        value6    ...  value6
value7         value7    value7        value7    ...  value7
value8         value8    value8        value8    ...  value8
value9         value9    value9        value9    ...  value9
```

I've managed to remove the top header by skipping rows e.g.(skiprows = 4). However, This still leaves the other headers and totals which append like so:

```
cabinet_name   group     pair          amount    ...  result
value1         value1    value1        value1    ...  value1
value2         value2    value2        value2    ...  value2
totals                               sum values
Account Name 2
Account No.2
cabinet_name   group     pair          amount    ...  result
value3         value3    value3        value3    ...  value3
value4         value4    value4        value4    ...  value4
totals                               sum values
Sales
00234
Description    group     pair          amount    ...  result
value5         value5    value5        value5    ...  value5
value6         value6    value6        value6    ...  value6
totals                               sum values
Inventory
00012345
Description    group     pair          amount    ...  result
value7         value7    value7        value7    ...  value7
value8         value8    value8        value8    ...  value8
value9         value9    value9        value9    ...  value9
totals                               sum values
```

Would be extremely grateful if someone could enlighten me on how to clean this sheet with pandas as all I've seen online are working on only 1 table in a single excel sheet.

Let me know if I've missed anything out, I would gladly edit this question.

---

I thought this might be useful,

My usual process for cleaning the files in excel, is to firstly delete the first 4 rows, only leaving

```
cabinet_name   group     pair          amount    ...  result
value1         value1    value1        value1    ...  value1
value2         value2    value2        value2    ...  value2
totals         *blank*   *blank*       sum values

Account Name 2
Account No.2
cabinet_name   group     pair          amount    ...  result
value3         value3    value3        value3    ...  value3
value4         value4    value4        value4    ...  value4
totals         *blank*   *blank*       sum values

Account Name 3
Account No.3
cabinet_name   group     pair          amount    ...  result
value5         value5    value5        value5    ...  value5
value6         value6    value6        value6    ...  value6
totals         *blank*   *blank*       sum values
```

Then I will filter **group** or **pair** to look for blank values in said column and deleting it.

This is the result of

```
print(df_total.head(8).to_dict())
```

```
import datetime
from numpy import nan
{'Date': {0: nan, 1: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 2: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 3: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 29, 0, 0), 4: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 31, 0, 0), 5: 
'Totals', 6: 'Net difference', 7: nan}, 
'Journal number': {0: nan, 1: 'AX009473', 2: 'AX009473', 3: 'AX003312', 4: 'AX009641', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Voucher': {0: nan, 1: 'TSPN-2021-3', 2: 'TSPN-2021-3', 3: 'GBJ-2021-1', 4: 'VIT-2021-1', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Posting type': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'Ledger journal', 4: 'Ledger journal', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Ledger account': {0: nan, 1: '00388211', 2: '00388211', 3: '00388211', 4: '00388211', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Description': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'DISBERSMENT FOR PETROL', 4: 'TAXI FAIR', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Unnamed: 6': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Unnamed: 7': {0: nan, 1: 'SGD', 2: 'USD', 3: 'SGD', 4: 'SGD', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Amount in transaction currency': {0: 'Debit', 1: 13.55, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 5, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 'Unnamed: 9': {0: 'Credit', 1: 0, 2: 25, 3: 52, 4: 0, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Amount in accounting currency': {0: 'Debit', 1: 13.55, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 5, 5: 18.55, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 'Unnamed: 11': {0: 'Credit', 1: 0, 2: 33.42, 3: 52, 4: 0, 5: 85.42, 6: 66.87, 7: nan}, 
'Amount in reporting currency': {0: 'Debit', 1: 13.55, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 5, 5: 18.55, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 'Unnamed: 13': {0: 'Credit', 1: 0, 2: 33.42, 3: 52, 4: 0, 5: 85.42, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 
'Unnamed: 14': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 'Unnamed: 15': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}, 'Unnamed: 16': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan}}
```

Created a specimen excel of what I have
[image: Excel untransformed]

**VS**

An excel of transformed data
[image: Excel transformed]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688022/removing-header-column-from-pandas-dataframe/44731471

Comment: @AndrewRyan Thank you! Will take a look right now

Comment: Hmm this is still working on 1 table per sheet only. I currently have multiple tables in the same sheet. Unless my understanding of the question is wrong... Could you further elaborate please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we could rework the column names a bit by adding the first row to it (this corrects the wanted columns whose names start with "Unnamed"). Then filter out the column names that start with "Unnamed" (the remaining unwanted ones), then using "Date" column, create a mask and filter the DataFrame:

```
df = df.rename(columns={**{f'Unnamed: {i}': j for i,j in zip((9,11,13), 
                                                             ('Amount in transaction currency',
                                                              'Amount in accounting currency',
                                                              'Amount in reporting currency'))}, 
                        **{'Unnamed: 7': 'Currency'}})

df.columns = [f'{col}_{first}' if first==first else col for col, first in zip(df.columns, df.loc[0])]
df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]]
date_filter = df['Date'].apply(isinstance, args=(datetime.datetime,))
df = df[date_filter]
```

The above code with an explicit loop to construct the list to modify column names:

```
cols = {'Unnamed: 7': 'Currency', 'Unnamed: 9': 'Amount in transaction currency', 
        'Unnamed: 11': 'Amount in accounting currency', 'Unnamed: 13': 'Amount in reporting currency'}
df = df.rename(columns=cols)

another_cols = []
for col, first in zip(df.columns, df.loc[0]):
    if first==first:
        another_cols.append(f'{col}_{first}')
    else:
        another_cols.append(col)
df.columns = another_cols
df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]]
date_filter = df['Date'].apply(isinstance, args=(datetime.datetime,))
df = df[date_filter]
```

Output:

```
                  Date Journal number      Voucher    Posting type  \
1  2021-01-01 00:00:00       AX009473  TSPN-2021-3             NaN   
2  2021-01-01 00:00:00       AX009473  TSPN-2021-3             NaN   
3  2021-01-29 00:00:00       AX003312   GBJ-2021-1  Ledger journal   
4  2021-01-31 00:00:00       AX009641   VIT-2021-1  Ledger journal   

  Ledger account             Description Currency  \
1       00388211                     NaN      SGD   
2       00388211                     NaN      USD   
3       00388211  DISBERSMENT FOR PETROL      SGD   
4       00388211               TAXI FAIR      SGD   

  Amount in transaction currency_Debit Amount in transaction currency_Credit  \
1                                13.55                                     0   
2                                    0                                    25   
3                                    0                                    52   
4                                    5                                     0   

  Amount in accounting currency_Debit Amount in accounting currency_Credit  \
1                               13.55                                    0   
2                                   0                                33.42   
3                                   0                                   52   
4                                   5                                    0   

  Amount in reporting currency_Debit Amount in reporting currency_Credit  
1                              13.55                                   0  
2                                  0                               33.42  
3                                  0                                  52  
4                                  5                                   0
```

Comment: @HOA `**` is the dictionary unpacking operator. We're combining two dictionaries by unpacking both inside another one. It's used to edit some of the column names; `rename` method can take a dictionary to rename columns.

Comment: Thanks so much enke! This really helped me understand your code! Kudos! Is it possible if we could connect on linked in?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the first 3 rows and the rows with "totals" and "sum values" have empty cells, so `dropna` should eliminate those rows. Then `drop_duplicates` with `keep=False` parameter should drop the the duplicate column names:

```
out = df.replace('', np.nan).replace(' ', np.nan).dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

I just can't test it because your `read_clipboard` complains about the format of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the unwanted rows like this.

```
df= df[~df['first_column_name'].str.startswith(('Company name','Account Name','Account No.','cabinet_name'))]
```

Comment: Thank you, Will attempt this right now!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, the account names and account No. are uniquely different. Is there a solution for this? I will edit my question to make it more obvious

Comment: str.startswith(()) checks and deletes line starting with "Account No". So it will delete all lines starting with "Account No". Hence it doesn't matter what is followed after "Account No". Hope it helps

Comment: Hi thats a good idea! However, the account name and number is a unique field and I wish to automate the process by not hardcoding the names

e.g. 
Inventory
001324

And another table will be 

Sales
1100

It doesn't have the words specific identifiable names